# Chmod crash version 13.10

Tags: 13.10, permissions, chmod, chown

I was watching a command line reference tutorial and testing out two commands, CHMOD and CHOWN. I ended up changing my root folder's permissions. What should I do? Version 13.10.

Comment: Do you have access to your recovery mode(you can access that when you boot in Advanced options for ubuntu)?

Comment: Changed them to _what_? Do you mean `/` or `/root`? Please post the  exact command you ran.

Comment: @terdon root folder.So it would be `/root`

Comment: @AvinashRaj do not assume. Root folder actually means `/`, not `/root` but since the OP is new to Linux, they may be using it to mean root's home, `/root`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command,

```
sudo chmod 700 /root
```